# Best place to store DB parameters in IBM Integration Bus

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

I am wondering where is the best place to store database parameters in IBM Integration Bus.  For example if we have dev, test and prod environment, each one with a separate database (of course), how would one best organize the changing of the DB connection properties? User variables? Some external service? Decision Manager repository? Cache variables (Shared or Extreme Scale Grid)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found it by myself and I'm posting ti here, maybe it will be useful for someone.
There is a [JDBCProviders configurable service](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bn28734_.htm?lang=en) that can be easily used for this kind of purpose.
Also [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/an37200_.htm?lang=en) can be found how to create configurable services.

Answer (score 5):

You can use another feature too, User Define Properties, and change the value with a properties file.
Not only for database, i use a lot to file processing.